# Print address function

Tags: c

How can I print the address of the instruction I am executing? For example let's consider the following main:

```
int main( void )
{
    //printf("......\n");
    printf("...Main...\n");
    uint32_t nb,delay;
    uint16_t result;
    DD_SPI_STATUS  status;
    //Get SPI driver instance
    DD_DRIVER_SPI* SPIdrv = DD_SPI_GetDriver(0);
    printf("...DD_DRIVER_SPI* SPIdrv = DD_SPI_GetDriver(0)...\n");
    DD_IRQ_Init();
    printf("...DD_IRQ_Init()...\n");

    // Initialize buffers
    for (nb = 0; nb < sizeof(TxBuffer); nb++)
    {
        TxBuffer[nb] = nb & 0xFF;
    }

    // Initialize the SPI driver
    SPIdrv->Initialize(SPI_callback);
    printf("...SPIdrv->Initialize(SPI_callback)...\n");
    // force driver reset
    SPIdrv->Control( DD_SPI_MODE_INACTIVE, 0);
    printf("...SPIdrv->Control( DD_SPI_MODE_INACTIVE, 0)...\n");
return 0;
}
```

How do I print the address of the instruction `SPIdrv-> Control (DD_SPI_MODE_INACTIVE, 0);` in such a way that by going to see the disassembled code I can immediately identify where I am?

Comment: There's no standard way to print instructions in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can print an address using `%p` formatting:

```
printf("SPIdrv->Initialize=%p\n", (void*)SPIdrv->Initialize);
```

There's no standard way to print the contents of the function as instructions. But if you google "C disassembler library" you'll find some functions you can download.

If you're trying to print the address in `main()` where you're calling the function, I don't think that's possible at all in standard C. GCC has an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) that allows you to get the address of a label, so you could do:

```
here: 
SPIdrv->Initialize(SPI_callback);
printf("Called SPIdrv->Initialize at %p\n", &&here);
```

Comment: I think they're asking how to print the address of the spot where `SPIdrv->Control()` is called.

Comment: Note that GCC is very likely to move the `here` label to some completely useless location if it thinks nothing can ever jump to that label, and you're only allowed to do a computed jump to a label from within the function that defines that label, so calling `printf` with the address of the label won't qualify as "something can jump to the label".

Answer (score 0):

It's non-standard, but if you're using `gcc` there's an extension to get the address of a label, so if you had:

```
debug_point:
    SPIdrv->Control( DD_SPI_MODE_INACTIVE, 0);
```

then `&&debug_point` would be a `void *` to that location in the code.